# Why do my app crashed when I delete the last record of a core data entity?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

In my app I use two core data entities shown in a table view, if there are more than one record, I can delete it with no problems, but if there is only one record, the app crash after touching the delete button:

Here is my code if needed to detect the issue, thanks in advance:

```
#import "PersonsTVC.h"
#import "Person.h"

@implementation PersonsTVC
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize selectedPerson;
@synthesize searchResults,titulosseccion;



- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    // 1 - Decide what Entity you want
    NSString *entityName = @"Person"; // Put your entity name here
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    // 2 - Request that Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    // 3 - Filter it if you want
    //request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Person.name = Blah"];

    // 4 - Sort it if you want
    // First sort descriptor (required for grouping into sections):
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    // Second sort descriptor (for the items within each section):
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstname" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortByDate, sortByName]];


   //
   // request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstname"
                                                                                     //ascending:YES
                                                                                      //selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    // 5 - Fetch it
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
    [self performFetch];
}




- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    NSString *sectionName = [theSection name];
    if ([sectionName isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        return @"Today";
    } else if ([sectionName isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        return @"Tomorrow";
    }
    else if ([sectionName isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        return @"Upcoming";
    }
    return @"Other";
}




- (void) viewDidLoad
{



    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}








- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setupFetchedResultsController];
}




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Perform segue to detail when a SEARCH table cell is touched
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Person Detail Segue" sender:tableView];
    }

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Persons Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    // Configure the cell...
    Person  *person = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show search results");
        person = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show normal data");
        person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }








    NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", person.firstname, person.surname];
    cell.textLabel.text = person.firstname;
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Yellow"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Black"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Black"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Grey"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Grey"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Red"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Blue"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Dark Green"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DarkGreen"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Light Green"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightGreen"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Light Blue"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightBlue"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Brown"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Brown"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Dark Orange"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DarkOrange"];



    }

    NSDate *fechasinformat = person.date;
    NSString *fecha0 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fechasinformat];


   cell.detailTextLabel.text = fecha0;



    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.tableView beginUpdates]; // Avoid  NSInternalInconsistencyException

        // Delete the person object that was swiped
        Person *personToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", personToDelete.firstname);
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:personToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

        // Delete the (now empty) row on the table
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self performFetch];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add Person Segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting PersonsTVC as a delegate of PersonDetailTVC");
        PersonDetailTVC *personDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        personDetailTVC.delegate = self;

        NSLog(@"Creating a new person and passing it to PersonDetailTVC");
        Person *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        personDetailTVC.person = newPerson;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Person Detail Segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting PersonsTVC as a delegate of PersonDetailTVC");
        PersonDetailTVC *personDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        personDetailTVC.delegate = self;

        // Store selected Person in selectedPerson property
        if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            self.selectedPerson = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        }
        else
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            self.selectedPerson = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

        NSLog(@"Passing selected person (%@) to PersonDetailTVC",    self.selectedPerson.firstname);
        personDetailTVC.person = self.selectedPerson;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Unidentified Segue Attempted!");
    }
}

- (void)theSaveButtonOnThePersonDetailTVCWasTapped:(PersonDetailTVC *)controller
{
    // do something here like refreshing the table or whatever

    // close the delegated view
    [controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Content Filtering

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    self.searchResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        Person* person = evaluatedObject;
        NSString* firstName = person.firstname;

        //searchText having length < 3 should not be considered
        if (!!searchText && [searchText length] < 3) {
            return YES;
        }

        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [firstName isEqualToString:scope])  {
            return ([firstName rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound);
        }
        return NO; //if nothing matches
    }]];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}



@end
```

Comment: where are your UIFetchedResultsController delegate methods?

Comment: @JAManfredi: I can't answer your question...i don't know what you mean..

Comment: Sorry I meant NSFetchedResultsController, but what is the error you are getting?

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with the core data, it is another error there; that is the error log: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (0) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are never setting the number of sections in the table via the tableview datasource method, this should take care of that:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}
```

If this doesn't solve the issue I think its due to you missing the NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate methods (at least controllerDidChangeContent:), this is another problem I answered a few days ago: [update CoreData Object not working correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220721/update-coredata-object-not-working-correct/20222978?noredirect=1#comment30233501_20222978)

Take a look at my answer and the corresponding code, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @JAManfredi, but that is not the solution as the app crash again showing the same error.

Comment: check out my edit, I answered something similar a few days ago, let me know if this helps

Comment: You would have to set your fetchedResultsController delegate and then check out the code below `#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsController Delegate`

Comment: Sorry @JAManfredi, I am not an experienced developer and I don't know exactly what to do, I have put -(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller { [self.tableView beginUpdates]; } below my #pragma mark section, but the crash again, could you be more clear and tell me exactly what code lines do I have to add to my code to solve the issue? So I would understand where is the mistake. Thank you in advance. I don't know exactly how to implement the delegate..

Answer (score 1):

A section can not be empty, so when you delete the last row you need to delete the section as well (and don't forget to create it before you add the first object):

```
// Delete the (now empty) row on the table
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

// Delete the section if needed
if ([[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] numberOfObjects] == 0)
    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self performFetch];
```

Comment: Thanks @Inafziger, adding your code results in an error: "No visible interface for UITableView declares the selector deleteSections"...

Comment: Oops, sorry I forgot the rest of the function...  See my update.